# Filter rows by condition in a column and copy some columns to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a "Template" sheet that contains a value in B1 that I want to be my condition.
I have an "onboarding" sheet from which I want to extract data from columns B to G for all rows if the values in column A = condition.
Then I want to copy filtered rows to the "Template" sheet, in a range from C4:H4 and below.

I found and adapted the code below. It is giving me an error on the line with Range.

> Run-time error '1004', Method #Range# of object '_Worksheet' failed

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i, x As Long
Dim Y As String
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("onboardings")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template") 'active sheet can get  you into trouble

condition= Worksheets("genericTemplate").Cells(1, 2).Value
FinalRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

x = 4
 
For i = 1 To FinalRow:
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = conditionThen
        Range(ws2.Cells(x, 3), ws2.Cells(x, 8)).Value = Range(ws1.Cells(i, 2), ws1.Cells(i, 7)).Value
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? And on what line does it stop?

Comment: Run-time error '1004', Method #Range# of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: When you click Debug, which line is highlighted?

Comment: line with Range

Answer (score 0):

I've tidied it up a bit, fixed a declaration and added some full qualification to your ranges - but I'm not sure it would help with the Range line. In testing, the below works.

Try this - see if you get the same error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    Dim Y As String
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("onboardings")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Template") 'active sheet can get  you into trouble
    
    Condition = Worksheets("genericTemplate").Cells(1, 2).Value
    FinalRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    x = 4
 
    For i = 1 To FinalRow
        If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = Condition Then
            Range(ws2.Cells(x, 3), ws2.Cells(x, 8)).Value = Range(ws1.Cells(i, 2), ws1.Cells(i, 7)).Value
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! Unfortunately it did not work. I get the same error message as before

Comment: Is it coping *some* of the data before erroring?